# Using DecimalFormat to format big double numbers

Tags: java

I am trying to use `DecimalFormat` to format double numbers to just print the number with 2 decimal places if it has fractional part else i want to print number as it is. When number is small, below code works fine but with big numbers, It's not working as expected.

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); //have tried just # too
    double d1 = 56789d;
    System.out.println(df.format(d1)); //works fine - prints 56789

    double d2 = 1234567879123456789d;
    System.out.println(df.format(d2)); // does not work
```

Second outputs `1234567879123456770` while I want `1234567879123456789`. For double values with decimal part, I just want to retain two decimal points.

Any suggestions on what's going wrong?

Comment: I suspect you are a victim of `double`'s (im)precision...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The explanation as to why the parsed value is off by `19` lies in the how `double` values are represented, as [IEEE floating-point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) with 53 bits of precision.  That is, for large values as you're inputting, the precision is actually greater than `1`.  The method [`Math.ulp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp(double)), for "unit in last place", gives the closest `double` values can be apart at the magnitude of its argument.

```
double d2 = 1234567879123456789d;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
System.out.println(Math.ulp(d2));
System.out.println(df.format(d2));
```

This outputs

```
256.0
1234567879123456770
```

So, you get the closest `double` value to the number you type in the source code.  [Section 3.10.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) covers `double` literals:

> The elements of the types float and double are those values that can be represented using the IEEE 754 32-bit single-precision and 64-bit double-precision binary floating-point formats, respectively.
>
> The details of proper input conversion from a Unicode string representation of a floating-point number to the internal IEEE 754 binary floating-point representation are described for the methods valueOf of class Float and class Double of the package java.lang.

And referring to [`Double.valueOf` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)):

> s is regarded as representing an exact decimal value in the usual "computerized scientific notation" or as an exact hexadecimal value; this exact numerical value is then conceptually converted to an "infinitely precise" binary value that is then rounded to type double by the usual round-to-nearest rule of IEEE 754 floating-point arithmetic [...]

Additionally, this value is still within the range of `long` values, which will still represent the integer value correctly.

```
long l2 = 1234567879123456789L;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
System.out.println(df.format(l2));
```

This outputs

```
1234567879123456789
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. lot of new things for me.

Comment: Didn't know about ulp. Nice answer! +1

Comment: Side question while we're at it: `StrictMath` also has `ulp()` methods, is there a difference between these and `Math`'s?

Comment: @fge Most likely no difference.  The source code I received when I downloaded Java 7 has both `Math`'s and `StrictMath`'s `ulp` methods that take a `double` delegating to the same thing: `sun.misc.FpUtils.ulp(d)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your literal has 19 decimal digits but a double only has 15.9 decimal digits of precision.