# Java DecimalFormat format function issue with large double number

Tags: java, format, double, decimalformat

```
    String pattern = "0.00";
    double number = 999999999999999999999d;
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
    decimalFormat.applyPattern(pattern);

    System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(number));
```

prints 1000000000000000000000.00

How can I print actual value.In this case I expect 999999999999999999999.00

Comment: A lot has been written on this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257166/java-floats-and-doubles-how-to-avoid-that-0-0-0-1-0-1-0-9000001 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423545/sum-of-decimal-number-in-java

Comment: practically do you use such a large number?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028675/using-decimalformat-to-format-big-double-numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to handle large number.

The BigDecimal class provides operations for arithmetic, scale manipulation, rounding, comparison, hashing, and format conversion. The toString() method provides a canonical representation of a BigDecimal.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a DecimalFormat issue - `999999999999999999999d` really does equal `1000000000000000000000`.  If you want to store very large integers like this one, you should use the [`BigInteger` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) - a `double` only has enough precision to store about 15-16 significant figures accurately.